# Find and replace instances of @foo, but not @@foo

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to use the @ sign as a means of indicating variables to swap in a string, but I also want to include the @ sign in the string of text.

## example:

```
Hello @website, you can email me at email@@website.com
```

Given this code, it would find-replace @website, and leave any instance of a double @@ alone; however, since JavaScript doesn't support negative lookbehind, I'm not sure how to modify the following regex to NOT select the instances of double @@:

`@([a-z0-9]+)`

## output:

```
Hello Patrick, you can email me at email@website.com
```

Notice how the @@ turned into a single @, an operation I'm sure I can handle after I figure out this first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another group and match something that isn’t an `@`:

```
/(^|[^@])@([a-z0-9]+)/
```

Then restore group 1 in the replacement, à la:

```
var result = input.replace(/(^|[^@])@([a-z0-9]+)/g, function (_, before, name) {
    return before + swap[name];
});
```

*However*, this makes representing `@@@somevariable` impossible, so I’d recommend you create a few rules:

```
var TOKEN = /@@|@([a-z0-9]+)|[^@]+|@/g;
var result = '';
var m;

while (m = TOKEN.exec(input)) {
    if (m[0] === '@@') {
        result += '@';
    } else if (m[1]) {
        result += swap[m[1]];
    } else {
        result += m[0];
    }
}
```

You might not ever need that, of course…

Comment: maybe use /(?:^|[^@])@([a-z0-9]+)/ to maintain the groups from the original question

Comment: @HunterLarco: It’d be inconvenient to restore like that.

Comment: Why? if he ever wants to grab what he replaced there is no need to clutter the groups with the leading value, based on how the question is presented

Comment: @HunterLarco: I’d assume the replacement is being done using `replace` as shown, and that the `@` has to be removed. *Not* matching it is just a waste of time; it’d take an extra check to see whether `@` was the first character before reinserting it, since `^` is an option…

Answer (score 1):

Is this that you're searching for ?

```
var subject = "Hello @website, you can email me at email@@website.com";
var result = subject.replace(/(.*?)(@\w+)(.*?)[@]{1}(\w+)/img, "$1Patrick$3$4");
//Hello Patrick, you can email me at email@website.com
```

http://regex101.com/r/hI3jH5

Comment: After seeing your work on another question I was curious to see your work on other regex questions. I've just looked at five recent ones... Solid work!

Comment: Always interesting to see what others are doing, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility based on what yo have mentioned so far.

```
var str = 'Hello @website, you can email me at email@@website.com';

var word = 'Patrick';

var result = str.replace(/(^|[^@])(@[a-z0-9]+)/i, '$1' + word).replace(/@{2,}/, '@');

console.log(result);
// output: Hello Patrick, you can email me at email@website.com
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNsjT/)